# Make Bash script accept either a filename or a line of text entered in the command line

Tags: bash

I'm working on a very basic ROT-5 (text only) converter, as a way of learning Bash and dabbling in cryptography and logic.

I've got it to work by taking the contents of a file and shifting the letters forward 5 places, as follows:

```
#!/bin/bash

echo $(<$1) 

echo $(<$1) | tr 'A-Za-z' 'F-ZA-Ef-za-e'
```

so for example if I enter the following command:

```
#./rot5.sh filename.txt
```

it will convert it fine. Is there any way to make it work so that if I was to enter the following:

```
./rot5.sh encodemysecretmessage
```

It would apply the `tr` to the `encodemysecretmessage` instead of looking for a filename?

Comment: Sure, just check if the file exists (`-f "$1"`) and if yes, run your current code, and if not, `echo "$1" |  tr ...`

Comment: in the case of passing in a string ... will it always be a single string or could it consist of multiple strings (and if so do they need to be quoted); for example, could the input be `encode my secret message` (without quotes), `'encode my secret message'` (with quotes)

Comment: You need to have some way to indicate to the script whether its argument(s) should be treated as filenames or strings to encode. Maybe an option flag, maybe like `./rot5.sh -f filename.txt` where the `-f` means "what follows is a filename, not a raw string"?

Comment: Don't put a solution in the question. Instead, [answer your own question](/help/self-answer). BTW, welcome to Stack Overflow! Check out the [tour], and [ask] if you want tips.

Comment: @markp-fuso that's a really good question - I've tried it with spaces in the entered text and it (I guess obviously with the benefit of hindsight) treats the space as a new instruction so doesn't process anything after the first space. I've tried it with a single inverted comma (gives me a `quote>` and a double inverted comma (gives me a `dquote>` - what's the way I would handle this kind of entry and (thinking about it) also escape characters - I guess just by leaving them as entered, really?

Comment: @wjandrea thanks! I've put the answer below

Comment: `$1` says to process argument #1; if you were to use `"$@"` you could process all arguments as a single unit; as for passing in escape characters ... gets a bit more interesting since at some point you would need to consider quoting the command line 'parameters' otherwise you could end up with some odd results (eg, `*` being expanded to a list of all files in the current directory)

Answer (score 2):

I'd recommend being explicit and using a command-line flag, for example, `-s`:

```
$ ./rot5.sh test.txt
foobar
kttgfw

$ ./rot5.sh -s "my secret message"
my secret message
rd xjhwjy rjxxflj
```

Here's an example implementation:

```
case $1 in
-s)
    # Handle data as a string.
    printf '%s\n' "$2"
    ;;
*)
    # Otherwise, handle data as a filename.
    cat -- "$1"
    ;;
esac | tee >(tr 'A-Za-z' 'F-ZA-Ef-za-e')
```

(How the last line works is [`tee`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/tee.1.html) takes its input and prints it as well as forwarding it to a file. Here I'm replacing the file with a [process substitution](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Process-Substitution.html#Process-Substitution).)

---

**Note**: This is just a barebones demo. For anything more complicated than this, handling command-line flags well is actually really difficult, so instead I'd probably use `getopts`, which requires a bit of boilerplate. [Here's a tutorial from a good source](https://wiki.bash-hackers.org/howto/getopts_tutorial), though I haven't read it myself.

Comment: Lots to unpack here, thanks. 

Answer (score 0):

Here's the working solution with the help from @Robert: Lots of thanks for that :)

```
#!/bin/bash

if [ -f "$1" ]; then
        echo $(<$1) 
        echo $(<$1) | tr 'A-Za-z' 'F-ZA-Ef-za-e'
else
        echo "$1"
        echo "$1" | tr 'A-Za-z' 'F-ZA-Ef-za-e'  
fi
```

Comment: Needs more quotes. `echo "$(<"$1")"` or else a whitespace-surrounded `*` in your input will be turned into a list of filenames in your current directory in output. (The inner quotes around `$1` are more ambiguously necessary; in some older versions of bash you could get "ambiguous redirect" errors when reading from a file with spaces in its name when that name was a redirection source in a variable, but I'm not sure that those old versions of bash supported `$(<file)` at all; otoh, doesn't hurt to err towards caution).

Comment: I'd recommend getting rid of the `echo $(<$1)` parts altogether -- `echo $(something)` almost never makes sense, because [the `echo` and the `$( )` basically cancel each other out](https://www.shellcheck.net/wiki/SC2005). I'd use `cat -- "$1"` (as in wjandrea's answer) to just print the raw file, and [using a redirect for `tr`](https://www.shellcheck.net/wiki/SC2002) (i.e. `tr ... <"$1"`).

Comment: Use `tr 'A-Za-z' 'F-ZA-Ef-za-e' < "$1"` in place of `echo $(<$1) | tr 'A-Za-z' 'F-ZA-Ef-za-e'`

Comment: Thanks everyone - that's a lot to look up (well a lot that I've looked up!) Appreciate it 